# tkinter window is blank after executing code

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm starting to code with Python and on my first application I have reached a brick wall. Any help on why this code is not displaying the widgets will be greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class ImprintPlusApp:

    def _init_(self, master):
        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, text = "Bienvenidos a Imprint Plus Manager")

        self.frame_crearorden = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_crearorden.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Nombre").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Email").grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Numero Cel/Tel").grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Información Adicional").grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 5)

        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_email = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_numtc = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_addinf = Text(self.frame_crearorden, width = 50, height = 10)

        self.entry_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_numtc.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_addinf.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Submit", command = self.submit).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 1, padx = 5)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Clear", command = self.clear).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 0, padx = 5)

    def submit(self):
        print ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get(1.0, "end")))
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(tite = "Orden #", message = "Orden Guardada")

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_email.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_numtc.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_addinf.delete(1.0, "end")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = ImprintPlusApp()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Everytime I launch the code I get a blank tkinter window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had a few problems.

1. You had an `_init_` method, not an `__init__` method, so the created object wasn't being initialized.
2. You have to send the root `tkinter` object to the application, with `app = ImprintPlusApp(root)`.
3. You had a `self.header_frame` once instead of `self.frame_header`.
4. You had a `columnspan = 0` (which is invalid) instead of `columnspan = 1` (which doesn't really need to be specified).

I've made the above changes in the code below. It may still need debugging, as I don't know exactly what design you had in mind.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class ImprintPlusApp:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = "Bienvenidos a Imprint Plus Manager")

        self.frame_crearorden = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_crearorden.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Nombre").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Email").grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Numero Cel/Tel").grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Información Adicional").grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 5)

        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_email = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_numtc = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_addinf = Text(self.frame_crearorden, width = 50, height = 10)

        self.entry_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_numtc.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_addinf.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Submit", command = self.submit).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 1, padx = 5)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Clear", command = self.clear).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 1, padx = 5)

    def submit(self):
        print ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get(1.0, "end")))
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(tite = "Orden #", message = "Orden Guardada")

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_email.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_numtc.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_addinf.delete(1.0, "end")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = ImprintPlusApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```